# Getting the sum of a column in WinForms

Tags: c#, sql-server, sum

I would like to get the sum of a column from database but the query returns -1. I have this query:

```
SELECT SUM(total) 
FROM bon
WHERE        
  (DATEPART(dd, data_adaugare) = DATEPART(dd, @p1)) 
  AND (DATEPART(mm, data_adaugare) = DATEPART(mm, @p1)) 
  AND (DATEPART(yy, data_adaugare) = DATEPART(yy, @p1))
```

and the code from C#:

```
decimal sumaa = 0;
DataTable suma = bonTableAdapter.Suma(DateTime.Now);

foreach (DataRow r in suma.Rows)
{
   sumaa += Convert.ToDecimal(r.ItemArray[0]);
}
```

Comment: If you change your query to `select total` instead of `select sum(total)`, and run it in your DBMS, what result do you see?

Comment: i don't get it ! Why does people give negative vote ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

total column in any record might be null. In that case use this.

```
SELECT SUM(isnull(total, 0))...
```

Comment: the correct syntax is ISNULL(SUM(total),0) but still it is not the wanted result. sumaa equals -1...

Comment: @EmilDumbazu: NO, read the answer.  The syntax that Mujtaba Hassan suggests will give you a better answer.  Your syntax checks whether the entire result of the SUM is NULL (which it won't be); his version only sums the non-null elements.

Comment: (And seriously, try to read an answer and understand it, instead of changing it and then saying it's wrong.  People are trying to help you here!)

Comment: Well that's different: saying that the posted code has a syntax error is not the same as saying that your syntax is correct.  Your syntax changes the meaning of the code that Mujtaba posted!  Also, that syntax works fine in MSSQL (though you should trim the ellipsis); what database are you using?

Answer (score 2):

you're missing a `+`

```
    decimal sumaa = 0;
    DataTable suma = bonTableAdapter.Suma(DateTime.Now);
    foreach (DataRow r in suma.Rows)
    {
        sumaa += Convert.ToDecimal(r.ItemArray[0]);
    }
```

Comment: yes it is a problem in code posted here but that's not the problem at all.

Comment: @EmilDumbazu ofcourse it is. without the `+` he`s not summing anything.

Comment: Maybe i haven't had the best statement in my comment but the + exists in my code!

Comment: If it exists, we can't see it, since it's not there! revise your question if so.

Comment: @EmilDumbazu: Then correct your question so that people are looking at the right code!